# careers.stackoverflow lists book I can't remember adding nor reading

Tags: support, jobs

My careers SO profile lists a book that I cannot

- remember having added to the list
- and *cannot* remember having read nor owning it (not on any shelf)
- isn't listed on my amazon order history and all english technical books I own I ordered via amazon

Is there any history as to when / how / who added such an item?

Disclaimer: It *is* totally possible that the title is collecting dust somewhere around here, I'm not blaming magic nor malice. Just *if* it's possible to investigate this, I'd like to :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please drop a note to careers@stackoverflow.com and refer to this post. We'll have a look in the database to see if there's a history.